# How do I convert NSData to file format (.mp4/.m4a)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, download, nsdata

I have some `NSData` variables which contain `.m4a`/`.mp4` file formats. I've tried looking at ways to convert the `NSData` into file format, with no luck. I need to convert it into a file, change some of it's metadata, and convert it back to `NSData`. Here's some code:

```
// This JSON basically gets the url of a .m4a
NSArray *preview = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.previewUrl"];

_previewData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[preview objectAtIndex:0]]];

[_previewData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    ANMovie* file = [[ANMovie alloc] initWithFile:_previewData]; // or .mp4
    NSData* jpegCover = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(artworkImage, 1.0);
    ANMetadata* metadata = [[ANMetadata alloc] init];
    metadata.albumCover = [[ANMetadataImage alloc] initWithImageData:jpegCover type:ANMetadataImageTypeJPG];
    [file setMovieMetadata:metadata];
    [file close];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `[[ANMovie alloc] initWithFile:]` expects a file, and you've passed it, I'm also assuming here, an `NSData*`.

Try:

```
ANMovie* file = [[ANMovie alloc] initWithFile:path];
```

Comment: I did that, but it just crashes. I can't see error because this is within an extension

Comment: I can't really help you without seeing what you are seeing in the console.  I don't know if there is no file at `path`, or if the crash is occurring a few lines down, or what.  If for some reason you can't view the console, at least throw some UIAlertViews in there to let you know if _previewData has any data in it, if the file saves correctly, etc.

Comment: _previewdata does have data in it, but that's about all i know now

Comment: I was able to copy the code into another project and see the errors it gives. Here is the error it was getting [http://imgur.com/rMkHK3o](http://imgur.com/rMkHK3o)